# My PDF prevents my audience from using their mice

Tags: pdf, two-column, dvi, evince

PDFTeX typesets my document in two columns. Unfortunately, when a person opens the PDF, the PDF does not let the person's mouse pick up text from one column, but rather interleaves text from left and right, which makes no sense.

To illustrate:

```
Here is some text      Here is some text
in the left column.    in the right column.
It speaks of           It speaks of
leftward things.       rightward things.
```

Interested in the left text, the person tries to highlight it with his mouse (maybe to copy it into an e-mail, for example). Regrettably, this is what his mouse picks up:

> Here is some text Here is some text in the left column. in the right
>   column. It speaks of It speaks of leftward things. rightward things.

Understandably, this annoys my audience.

Solutions?

**FURTHER INFORMATION**

I am using LaTeX's `report` class in `\twocolumn` mode. Packages used are probably irrelevant to my question, but happen to be these: ifthen; graphicx; amsmath; caption; hyperref.

I do not know whether my problem is a TeX issue, a LaTeX issue, a DVI issue (but does PDFTeX even use DVI?), or a PDFTeX issue. Actually, I do not believe that it is a PDFTeX issue, since the problem arises even if I use `latex` and `dvipdf` instead of `pdflatex`.

My audience knows little or nothing about TeX, so it does no good to provide the audience my LaTeX source. The mouse problem only makes them complain that I should instead have used Microsoft Word—which, obviously, I would rather not do.

**UPDATE**

A developer of Evince, the PDF reader, has kindly come here to comment below. He has not posted an *answer* as such, but his *comments* are very much worth reading. You can find his comments by the name @gpoo both under this question and under the accepted answer below.

(Since the answerer has noted that he prefers other software, I should note that I rather like Evince, myself. In fact, I use Evince even though I do not use GNOME, with which Evince is usually associated.)

**EXAMPLE**

A boring example follows. If you compile it to PDF, open the PDF, and try to copy text from the left column with your mouse, it does not work. Why not?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.

\section{First}

  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.

  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.

  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.

\section{second}

  Here is some text. Here is more text.

  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
  Here is some text. Here is more text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can select text columnwise (using `Adobe Reader`), there is no mixing between columns

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Really? I had not been using `Adobe Reader`, but `Evince`. I will now try `Adobe Reader` and report back.

Comment: This is a viewer issue. Adobe Reader, Skim and Preview all pick up the first column. I can only reproduce the problem with Evince, and I had long since concluded that Evince should never be used.

Comment: @IanThompson: Apparently yes. I tested with `okular` as well -- the copying is as expected. I've not installed evince at all.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: You have just saved me many hours! I appreciate it. Maybe you have so much reputation on this site that it no longer matters to you, but if you made your comment an answer, I should like to upvote it.

Comment: @IanThompson: You have just saved me many hours! I appreciate it. Maybe you have so much reputation on this site that it no longer matters to you, but if you made your comment an answer, I should like to upvote it. I can now confirm that mice work in `Adobe Reader` as they ought.

Comment: @IanThompson: I leave it to you (You made more tests). I will upvote too then ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer --- answered.

Comment: It works as expected with Evince 3.18, which makes sense if newer Okular also works (both use Poppler to render the document).

Comment: User @gpoo is too humble to say it, so I will note it here. He is developer of the Evince software we have been discussing. I have updated the question in light of his comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a viewer issue. Adobe Reader, Skim and Preview all pick up the first column, as you would expect. I can only reproduce the issue with old versions of Evince and Okular. I don't have a recent version of either of these viewers, but @Christian Hupfer and @gpoo have tested more up to date versions of Okular and Evince and found that they both work. For other reasons, I have long since concluded that Evince should never be used. I haven't seen software that crashes so often since Windows 95.

Comment: Perhaps you should add `okular` as working well too. (I will delete this comment soon)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I will try `okular` on your advice.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer --- hmm, Okular reproduces the problem on my system! That said, the version on my machine (0.9.4) is out of date; it's an old installation, and I don't have root privileges so I can't upgrade it easily. What version do you have?

Comment: @IanThompson: `0.21.3` -- not the newest, as far as I know. (OpenSuSE 13.2, released some months ago)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer --- I have edited the answer in view of this.

Comment: @IanThompson: Thanks (Can't upvote again ;-))

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: For information, `okular 0.20.2` fails the test -- which you will already have concluded from Ian's comment.

Comment: @thb: Well -- 0.20.2. is newer than 0.9.4 -- the conclusion should be rather that it should work with `0.20.2`, but apparently, this not the case!

Comment: I have filed a bug report against `evince`: [https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=762096].

Comment: The answer is misleading as it ignores the fact that both Evince and Okular uses the Poppler library to render PDF. If there is any bug on this, it is in Poppler.That said, both documents works fine with Evince 3.18 and Poppler 0.39.

Comment: @gpoo --- It doesn't matter if they use Poppler or if they are coded from scratch in FORTRAN IV. This *is* a viewer issue, it *does* affect old versions of Okular and Evince, and it *doesn't* affect Skim, Preview or Adobe Reader. None of this is misleading.

Comment: It does. The selection text is handled by Poppler, as Evince and Okular passes the coordinates and Poppler give the selected text back. The very reason that old versions of both fail and newer versions of both work. As a matter of fact, you can try poppler-glib-demo in different versions to check it by yourself.

Comment: @gpoo --- You have provided some extra information about the problem, but the answer is not misleading.

Comment: It is misleading if the answer does not reflect that newer versions of Evince do not have the problem (or to be more precise, that Okular and Evince with newer version of Poppler work)

Comment: @gpoo  --- The answer *does* say that the issue has only been observed using old versions of Okular and Evince. It also says that new versions of Okular work properly. It didn't say that new versions of Evince work because at the time of posting, nobody had tested this. Since you have tested an up to date version of Evince, I have edited the answer.

Comment: @IanThompson Your two last sentences are very aggressive and subjective...